# Coldfusion - Form submission somehow different on mobile?

Tags: forms, mobile, coldfusion

So I have a very strange problem.  I have a simple form setup to collect email / password.  On the submission page I run these through a query to check if the user exists.  This all works fine on desktop, but using it on mobile results in the query always returning 0 for record count.

```
<form action="test2.cfm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="EN">
Email Address :  <input type="text" name="strEmail" style="width: 200px;"> 
Password : <input type="password" name="strPassword" style="width: 200px;">
<br /><input type="submit" value="LOGIN"></td>
</form>

<cfquery name="getParticipant" datasource="#request.dbDSN#" username="#request.dbUsername#" password="#request.dbPassword#">
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE email = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.strEmail#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
AND password = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.strPassword#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>
    record count: #getParticipant.recordCount#
</cfoutput>
```

As I've stated this code works fine when an existing user attempts to login on a desktop computer.  The EXACT same code returns 0 when a login is attempted on mobile.

What is going on???

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason the results would be different, unless maybe the application has mobile specific code not mentioned above?  Log in as the same user from the desktop and mobile, and compare the values being passed to the action page.  (Side note, passwords shouldn't be stored in plain text - should be hashed)

Comment: @Ageax The passed values appear to be exactly the same on desktop and mobile.  I've gone so far as to setup a test page with JUST this code to ensure nothing else is getting in the way, and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: 1. Do a `<cfdump>`  of form. Just to see if anything interesting happens. 2. Use `trim()` 3. OT: on the email, use a `type="email"`. That has nothing to do with your problem, but it may make for a better UI experience. 4. What version of CF are you using?

Comment: @user1110562 - Not sure how you checked it, but don't just rely on eyeballing it. Dump both values, lengths, etc..  The length checks will help determine it it's a white space issue.. Also, do a dump of the two queries and check the values.